# How to find name of various files contained in a folder using function os.listdir()

Tags: python, class

```
import os
file_list = os.listdir("C:\Users\TE123137\Desktop\prank")
print (file_list)
```

Output:

```
================================ RESTART ================================
>>>
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting and add more detail to your question.

Comment: Your code doesn't print `===...RESTART...===`.  What *does* it print?

Comment: That code works (if you remove the space after print). What is the problem exactly?